# Write a calendar script for an item to repeat every 15th of the month or on the Friday before if it falls on Saturday or Sunday

Tags: icalendar

I've tried several ways and nothing is working correctly.  Here's one:

```
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTHDAY=15;BYSETPOS=-1;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20220415
```

Answer (score 1):

Persistence pays off.  Here's what worked.

```
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;BYMONTHDAY=13,14,15;BYSETPOS=-1
```